# Could someone point out the error in my jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting

I'm making a script to open all links on a page when I click a button in my toolbar. What exactly is wrong with the following code?

```
        function performCommand(event) {  
            if (event.command == "open-tests") {
                $('a').each(function(index, elem) {
                    window.open($(elem).attr('href'));
                });
            }  
        }
```

As far as getting to the function, it does this fine, as if I comment out the if statement and put in a simple alert, it will work as expected. However the above code does not work.

Comment: Which browser are you using to test this? event.command probably is bounded to MSIE

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ATKKU/), given that everything in context is correct, and you receive an object exactly like the one you're expecting.

Comment: I'm using Safari, as it's a Safari extension. Here's how I have it set up, it basically alleviates some of the identification of things. http://i.imgur.com/widJi.png And here's the HTML code I have in the global page. http://cl.ly/3u131Y0b100n1V2y3N0z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you disable your PopUp Manager or are you using any other kind of adblocker / secure plugin?

Despite that Safari refuses to window.open when called in a callback

more to read:
http://jensarps.de/2009/08/21/safari-and-window-open/

Answer (score 7):

There is no standard `command` property of the [event object provided by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Why do you think there is one?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that. What I'm doing in this case is a Safari extension (that's where the button comes from) and part of the API is the command. That part works fine.